# Read XML file in Python, search for key in a line and replace value

Tags: python, xml, xpath, key

I have an XML file that looks like this!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <root>    
  <child>    
   <add key="setid" value=".\print\data1" />    
    <add key="getid" value=".\print\data2" />    
    <add key="holdingid" value=".\print\data3" />    
   </child>    
 </root>
```

I want to read a line in the XML, search for a key match and replace a value in that line with `.\donotpritnnt\data1`

I can do this in NANT using XMLPOKE and xpath.
Tried this with dict, list (replacing with positionID), split (not good enough code to show here)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your XML code is in **test.xml** in the working directory.

```
new_content = []
with open("test.xml") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        newline = line
        if 'key="setid"' in line:
            newline =  line[:line.find("value=")] + 'value=".\donotpritnnt\data1" />\n'
        new_content += [newline]
with open('test.xml', 'w') as f:
    for line in new_content:
        f.write(line)
```

Its not the nicest way, but it works for the example you provided, and may also be extentable since it iterates over the file and looks at each line. Further improvements may probably by using *regex* etc.

Comment: serves the purpose. Thank you.